# Aprroximating the area of a surface of revolution using simpsons rule

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, surfaces

Consider the surface of revolution generated from rotating the curve $3xe^x$ from $0 \leq x \leq 1$ about the $x$-axis.

So, the integral will look like:

$$\int_0^1 6 \pi e^xx \sqrt{(3e^xx+3e^x)^2+1} \, dx$$

I need to approximate this integral using simpsons rule with $n=10$... After a billion attempts I can't seem to get it right! The correct answer is supposed to be 209.894506

Can somebody walk me through the steps on this one? I feel like i'm going crazy

Comment: It is all focused calculation. For reference on steps, please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832415/using-simpsons-rule-to-approximate-the-arclength-of-y-ln9x3-from-0-leq/3832469#3832469

Comment: Can you write what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=10$ then $\Delta x = (1-0)/10 = 0.1$.
Now
$$
\begin{split}
\int_a^b f(x)\ dx
 \approx \frac{\Delta x}{3} \left[f(0) + 4f(0.1) + 2f(0.2) \\
                                       + 4f(0.3) + 2f(0.4) \\
                                       + 4f(0.5) + 2f(0.6) \\
                                       + 4f(0.7) + 2f(0.8) \\
                                       + 4f(0.9) +  f(1.0)\right]
\end{split}
$$